# expend valid string in byte array

Tags: python

array x contains string followed by all zeros. I need expand the string but keep x array's size the same.

e.g.:

```
def modify(x,y):
    return x

# input x and y
x = bytes([0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00])
y = 'EFGH'
print(x)
x = modify(x,y)
#output x
print(x)
```

expected output:

```
 b'ABCD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
 b'ABCDEFGH\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

What's propery way to do it in python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ljust` to add a number of characters to make the resulting `bytes` the length you want:

```
>>> b'ABCD'.ljust(20, b'\0')
b'ABCD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

So, all in all: strip the trailing zeroes out of the source bytes, add in the bit you want to add, re-pad back to the original length:

```
>>> x = bytes([0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00])
>>> y = b'EFGH'
>>> (x.rstrip(b"\x00") + y).ljust(len(x), b"\x00")
b'ABCDEFGH\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>>
```

Comment: good suggestion,  x is available buffers now, I would reused it. this method will create a new buffer, right?

Comment: Yes. You never mentioned anything about buffers; `bytes` are immutable.